# Python Dataframe rowwise min and max with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, minmax

My dataframe has nans. But I am trying to find row wise min and max. How do I find it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[12,NaN,13],"B":[45,12,65],"C":[63,78,NaN]})

df= 
    A    B     C
0   12   45    63
1   NaN  12   78
2   13   65    NaN
```

I am tring to find min and max in each row and difference between them in column `A` `B` and `C`.
My code:

```
poacols = ['A','B','C']
df['dif'] = np.nanmax(df[poacols])-np.nanmin(df[poacols])
```

Present output:

```
df['dif'] = 
0    66
1    66
2    66
```

Expected output:

```
df['dif'] = 
0    51
1    66
2    52
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should add the axis=1, check the min and max for each row

```
np.nanmax(df[poacols],1)-np.nanmin(df[poacols],1)
Out[81]: array([51., 66., 52.])
```